# What do when strong typing with two types needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm quite newbie to mvc and as I'm designing some blog-like web app I want to know one thing from more experianced. The problem is that I have a view of a blog article and box for typing comments for it. The perfect, abstract solution would be to type this view strongly with a class of both article and comment, but as we know, it's not possible. 
What will be the best way to handle this case? As it's a View of article, this should typed with article class. On the other hand - it will be easier to type it with comment class and pass article fields with ViewBag. I don't find it right as logically it shouldn't be typed  with a class, that isn't directly represented here (article is the main one).

What are other possible solution to add and validate comments easily and do it in a clear way?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** main "problem" is not to handle list of existing comments, but to add new one - can I use with ViewModel FormCollection in this case easily on the controller side?

Comment: why not having a BlogPost class which has a post and a comments class?

Comment: I think composition is a better solution, but you could inherit multiple interfaces instead of multiple classes.  Multiple interface inheritance is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use a ViewModel in this instance.  Something like this:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BlogPostViewModel
{
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**: the connecting object between a domain model (or models) [in your case `Comment` and `Article`] and a View [in your case, your blog post view].

Your View would look something like this:

```
@model BlogPostViewModel

@* you can reference Model.Article, as well as Model.Comments here *@
```

Here is a good working example of [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx).

**Edit**: and then for an Action method to receive your POSTed data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourBlogView(BlogPostViewModel bpvm)
{
    // here you have access to the binded model
    // i.e. bpvm.Article
}
```

Comment: ok, but my problem (mainly) is to add comment in the same view. Can I use in this case FormCollection on the controller side to handle that new one?

Comment: @deha You would use inputs (whether direct DOM or InputExtensions) to pass this new data (comments) to a POST action.

Comment: can you show some simple code example? I'm mainly interested in the controller method parameters...

Comment: @deha I have edited my post to show the simple Controller Action method.

Comment: so I guess that BlogPostViewModel should contain string field like NewComment and in the view render the editor for it?

Answer (score 2):

> The perfect, abstract solution would be to type this view strongly with a class of both article and comment, but as we know, it's not possible.

But it is possible. And it's called a ViewModel.

You seem to be fixated a little on the CRUD model. It looks mainstream but that's because it's the only approach that lends itself to code-generation and templating.

To get a better perspective, take a look at the AccountModels in the standard MVC templates.

Answer (score 2):

Use a new model:

```
public class ArticleAndCommentsModel {
    public ArticleModel Article { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

An your view will inherit `ViewPage<ArticleAndCommentsModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

I Can see two options

1. Create a viewmodel with the article and a comments collection
2. Render the comment section as a separate view (on the same page)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `ViewModel` approach suggested by the others would be to put the `Article` in the `ViewBag` and reference it from there and let the `Comment` be the page's model. This assumes the user doesn't modify the article.